# VSCode insert double round brackets around a selection or a single Word

Tags: visual-studio-code

How could I insert double brackets like this around selected text with a keyboard shortcut(ctrl+alt+d for example):

((Selected Text))

I know that, its possible to surround the selection with brackets by selecting a text and pressing `((`.

How could I do it with a keybinding around a single word on the cursor position without selecting the word?

Comment: If you want it in one press, you may check this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) for customizing a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command)

Add the following keybindings

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+d",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorHasSelection",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { 
      "sequence": [
        "editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch",
        { "command": "type", "args": { "text": "((" } }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "ctrl+alt+d",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection",
    "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
    "args": { 
      "sequence": [
        { "command": "type", "args": { "text": "((" } }
      ]
    }
  }
```

It also works with multi cursors.

**Edit** Marks comment on using `"(("`

Comment: You don't need the two `type` calls if you `{ "command": "type", "args": { "text": "((" } }`

Comment: @Mark That `type` really is smart handled, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pressing

> ctrl+d

selects the word under cursor, then you could press double brackets "((" to  insert brackets around the word